# Android - getIntExtra results in default value in onActivityResult

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I'm trying to allow a user to select an image from their gallery to replace an existing one in my activity (which was programatically added based on DB values). Here's the portion of my code that's causing some issues:

```
public void requestImage(int imageID){
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra("imageID",imageID);
    intent.setType("image/*");
    Log.v("requestImage",Integer.toString(intent.getIntExtra("imageID",0)));
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
        Uri uri = data.getData();

        try {
            Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uri);
            int imageID = data.getIntExtra("imageID",0);
            Log.v("onactivityresult",Integer.toString(imageID));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The goal is to get the ID of the image that was selected for this function, which I'm passing in to requestImage, through to onActivityResult. onActivityResult contains the code for setting the image's bitmap based on the image selected by the user (omitted from code sample for conciseness).

Note the two logging statements, which result in:

```
05-27 15:51:31.756 7769-7769/com.praytoday.app.praytoday V/requestImage: 12

05-27 15:45:55.511 2037-2037/com.praytoday.app.praytoday V/onactivityresult: 0
```

As you'll notice in the logging statements, the first log is actually getting the int from the intent itself, so I am certain it's being set correctly (and there aren't any type issues here).

It seems to me that data must not be the same intent (please excuse my lack of knowledge on the subject of intents - this is pretty new to me).

Things that I have tried:

- Using getIntent() instead of data
- Not using the createChooser, and instead just using the plain intent
- Looking at every question/answer about this I could find

Any help in determining why this extra value is not in the data argument would be much appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: If I remember correctly, the intent passed is not the intent you passed - meaning any arguments in that intent is not returned. But I can be wrong

Comment: That really seems like it would defeat the purpose! It seems like it has to be possible to pass an argument through somehow - I really thought this was the way but I guess maybe it isn't.

Comment: I haven't used startActivityForResult in a long time, though, so don't take it as an answer. There may be something that resets it as a result of an error in the framework.

Comment: So other than startActivityForResult, any recommendations on a better way to get the gallery activity started, where passing in an argument actually works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went ahead and just set a global variable to store which image is currently set for replacement. requestImage sets it to the current image ID, and then onActivityResult uses that variable. Not very elegant, but it works!